# How to place a particular compiled .class file (or files) into META-INF/services

Tags: java, maven, class, classpath

I want one of my compiled classes to be added into `META-INF/services` folder inside of my uber-jar. Is it something to be configured inside `maven-shade-plugin`?

This is the page which requires placing the file into `META-INF/services`: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.2/docs/modules/embedded/#defining-an-embedded-module

> This means that every JAR should contain a file
> org.apache.flink.statefun.sdk.spi.StatefulFunctionModule in the
> META_INF/services resource directory that lists all available modules
> that it provides.

`MyClass` implements `StatefulFunctionModule`, but I'm not sure if I should place it alone, or place it as `org/package1/package2/MyClass.class` (assuming that its package path is `org.package1.package2`)

It looks like all files inside `META-INF/services` are named according to their original package path, e.g. my class would be named as `org.package1.package2.MyClass` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`META-INF/services` does not contain classes, it contains **text** files (named after the SPI - Service Provider Interface), which lists the class names that implement that SPI. That means you would have a file called `META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.statefun.sdk.spi.StatefulFunctionModule`, and its contents is:

```
org.package1.package2.MyClass
```

or - if you have multiple implementations:

```
org.package1.package2.MyClass
org.package1.package2.MyOtherClass
```

(that is, one class name per line)

Generally, you would add this file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services`, though there might be Maven plugins that can generate them for you (I'm not sure though).

Note that if you use a modular Java project, you would (also) need to define this in `module-info.java` as:

```java
module your.modulename {
    // ...
    provides org.apache.flink.statefun.sdk.spi.StatefulFunctionModule
        with org.package1.package2.MyClass; 
}
```